# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4' " occured when deploying django project to PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to deploy my django project to PythonAnywhere referring to https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/.
When I executed this command,

```
pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.6 https://github.com/my_git_url.git
```

The following error happened: (actually some texts are omitted because it's long)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kanchi0914/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kanchi0914/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kanchi0914/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 52, in <module>
```

`django-bootstrap4`and`bootstrap4` seems to be correctlly installed.

```
23:45 ~ $ pip3.6 install --user django-bootstrap4                                                                      
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Requirement already satisfied: django-bootstrap4 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django-bootstrap4) (4.6.0)
```

I guessed these sites would be useful, tried some solutions, but situation did not change.
https://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/deploy.html
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12404/
Off cource I confirmed my project work well in my local env.
What should I do?
thanks.

Comment: pip freeze and see is it installed and make sure that you added it in installed apps in your settings file

Comment: I found "django-bootstrap-form" was installed and guessed this caused some issues because of django's version differences. I tried fix these dependencies, but the problem was not solved after all. I ended up using heroku instead of PythonAnywhere, for some reasons such as execution speed and more, and that works currently. thanks.

Comment: Looks like `django-bootstrap4` was installed outside your virtual environment. It's in `./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.1)` not in `/home/kanchi0914/.virtualenvs/kanchi0914.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` Was it included in requiremants.txt that `pa_autoconfigure_django.py` looks for when it creates virtual environment? Vide https://github.com/pythonanywhere/helper_scripts/blob/master/pythonanywhere/django_project.py#L30

Answer (score 0):

I had this one time. Maybe you have to use pip3 if you are using python 3. Or pip if you are using python 2. Packages installed with pip3 won't work in python 2 and vice versa if your python version is 2. Not sure if this helps.